# Bound the derivative norm of a convolution by the function norm

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Is there a bound of the form

$$
\|(f*\phi_\epsilon)'\|_{L^2}\leq C(\epsilon) \|f\|_{L^2},
$$
where $\{\phi_\epsilon\}$ are standard mollifiers, and $C(\epsilon)$ does not depend on $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(f*\phi_\epsilon)' = f*\phi_\epsilon'$. Now use Young's inequality, giving 
$$ \|f*\phi_\epsilon'\|_2 \le \|f\|_2 \cdot \|\phi_\epsilon'\|_1 $$

Comment: and $\|\phi_\epsilon '\|=\frac{1}{\epsilon}\|(\phi')_\epsilon\|=\frac{1}{\epsilon}\|(\phi')_1\|$. Thanks